# PHP make round function return an int

Tags: php, casting, int, rounding

the round() function returns a float but I want to typecast this returned float to an int. What is the best way to this?

This is what I had in mind but I am not sure if it's the right/best way. Anyone can help me out with some info?

```
 $value = round(50000500 / 10000);

 return (int) $value;
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: round(50000500 / 10000, 0) http://php.net/manual/fr/function.round.php

Comment: use intval($value) http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php.

before post that kind of question once google it

Comment: I think it's okay if you use something like `$value = (int) ....`

Comment: you can use [floor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) or [ceil](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) functions.

Comment: This is a good solution for your problem. Easy and readable